# Composing React Components for Reusability

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS app to display the movies and sort them in ascending and descending order. I have App.js component, which loads the movies from an API and then sends the movies to MovieList component.

```
function App() {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies() 
  }, [])

  const fetchMovies = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('SOMEURLTOMOVIES')
    let result = await response.json() 
    setMovies(result.Search)
  }

  const handleSort = () => {
    let sortedMovies = movies.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.Title - a.Title 
    })

    console.log(sortedMovies)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick = {handleSort}>Sort</button>
        <MovieList movies = {movies} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The MovieList component is shown below:

```
function MovieList(props) {

  const movieItems = props.movies.map((movie) => {
    return <li key = {movie.imdbID}>{movie.Title}</li>
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {movieItems}
    </div>
  )

}
```

The movies are displayed correctly. The first thing to notice is that the fetchMovies is right inside the Component. I see this pattern in most of React apps. What if they want to perform fetchMovies from somewhere else. I guess devs will then move it into a separate function etc.

Another thing about App.js function is the sort function (currently not working). Only App component can sort the movies. What if some other component is also interested in sorting the movies? How would we do that?

Comment: So do you want to avoid prop drilling or something? Maybe look at React context and see if it covers your needs? Hard to answer without a concrete example of what you wanna do...

Comment: I guess my question is more around how do people implement sort in React in such a way that the sort functionality can be reused in other components.

Comment: Reused how, though? Do you want the components to modify the state of `App`? To sort their own movies? How do you want this to be reused?

Comment: The question is too broad to answer and there are resources, old and new outlining design patterns for React. Recently there is work going into https://www.patterns.dev/.

Comment: I see two options, you can move this fetch logic into a custom hook and reuse it in parts of the app that its needed. If you only want to fetch once, and re-use the data across the app, you would want to put the data into the context API.

Comment: My idea of reused was that maybe there was a favorites page which lists all the movies favorite by the user. And on that page user wants to sort the movies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it depends on the goals. If you are trying to make it so the movies are only fetched once and all components use the data from that fetch, you will use React Context. However, context shouldn't be used as a get-out-of-jail-free card when you need only code re-use and not shared state.

Typically, for code reuse purposes, you'd put this logic in [a custom hook](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks).

```
const useMovies = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies() 
  }, [])

  const fetchMovies = async () => {
    let response = await fetch('SOMEURLTOMOVIES')
    let result = await response.json() 
    setMovies(result.Search)
  }

  const sort = () => {
    let sortedMovies = movies.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.Title - a.Title 
    })

    return sortedMovies 
  }

  return { movies, sort } 
}
```